# How to prove that any regular map $\phi : \Bbb P^1 \to \Bbb A^n(\Bbb C)$ maps $\Bbb P^1$ to point.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How to prove that any regular map $\phi : \Bbb P^1 \to \Bbb A^n(\Bbb C)$ maps $\Bbb P^1$ to point. Now $\phi=(F_1/G_1,...,F_n/G_n)$ where $F_i/G_i$ is a regular function.
Now how do I conclude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k$ be algebraically closed. A morphism $f: \mathbb{P}^r \to \mathbb{A}^n$ induces a $k$-homomorphism $\varphi: \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{A}^n) = k[x_1,\dots,x_n] \to \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{P}^r) = k$. As a $k$-homomorphism, $\varphi$ is surjective and so it must be the quotient map by a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_P$. Then $f$ simply maps $\mathbb{P}^r$ to $P$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\phi$ is regular, by continuity its image is a limited set in $\mathbb{A}^n(\mathbb{C})$. Using any chart of $\mathbb{P}^1$, you can obtain a holomorphic mapping from $\mathbb{C}^1$ to $\mathbb{A}^n(\mathbb{C})$ which is globally holomorphic and limited. Therefore it is constant, that is, its image is only one point. It extends to the entire $\mathbb{P}^1$ by continuity.

Comment: Will you please explain? I didn't get this chart and globally holomorphic things.

Comment: When you wrote $\phi$ as quotients of functions in each coordinate that's exactly the coordinates you need. To understand this geometrically check out the charts in the Riemann Sphere (which is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$ and therefore both are compact). By "globally holomorphic" I meant that it descends to an entire funtion (holomorphic in the entire complex plane).]